# Unit testing onClick handler using Jest in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following code which sets a custom handler to each element (which can be a `button` or a `li`) click.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   this._setCallbackToItemLinks(nextProps);
}

_setCallbackToItemLinks(props) {
    const items = props && props.items;
    items.forEach(item => {
      item.links.forEach(link => {
        this._setCallbackToLink(link);
      });
    });
 }



 _setCallbackToLink(link) {
    link.onClickFromProps = link.onClick;
    link.onClick = e => this._onItemClick(e, link.onClickFromProps);
 }



onItemClick(e, onClickFromProps) {
    console.log("Custom click event handler called");
    if (onClickFromProps) 
      onClickFromProps(e);
}
```

I want to unit test the above functionality using Jest.

```
const component= mount(<Comp />);
const mock2 = jest.fn();
component.setProps({ items: [{links: [{ name: 'Test', key: 'Test', url: 'Test', onClick: mock2 }]}] });
const link= component.find('.nav-link');
navLink.simulate('click');
expect(mock2.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
```

the test is passing, however I am not getting the `console.log` statement written in `onItemClick` method. When I try to debug this test, it is not even going into `onItemClick` after the simulate click is called.

the `navLink` does show an `<a>` tag.

when I log `navLink.props().onClick`, it shows `[Function: bound]`

Comment: Check this binding in methods

Comment: Not sure if it was a mis-paste, but your code is missing one last `}`.

Comment: @Alex Works fine when I test it in the browser, its only the test which is failing.

Comment: Maybe component.find instead of autocomplete.find?

Comment: @Alex sorry it was `component.find`. Corrected the typo

Comment: last attempt and I give up: `component.find('.nav-link').first()` :)